# Unrealistically long process times displayed in top

Tags: centos, process, top

I (partly) manage a small cluster and we are having some problems on a few nodes (running CentOS 6.4). Some processes show exceptionally long run-times in 'top', even though the computer has been rebooted *very* recently. See here for an example:
[image]

Note - up time only 2 days, 'init' process time almost 4 million hours.

The problems maybe started after the clocks changed but the system time seems to be correct, as shown at the bottom of the screenshot.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this, and more importantly how to fix it?

Edit - ps:
[image]

Comment: What does `ps` say?

Comment: Have just added another screenshot

Comment: Can  you check [this](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6421)? If it is the same bug.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that might have fixed it. I'll check back in after a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to [this](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6421) bug, and a hard reset solved the problem. (previous soft resets didn't do anything...)

Thanks to taliezin who commented with the solution.